# Python: How to import 2.7 module into 3.4 program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, import

### Question:

Is it possible to import a module I wrote in python 2.7 into a 3.4 program that I wrote?

### Background:

I've tried doing this and as expected it throws a `SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax`, once it sees the first `print "string literal"` statement instead of 3.4's `print()`.  There are a few additional incompatible code snippets, like `import Tkinter` instead of `tkinter`.  The 2.7 module must remain in 2.7 because one of its dependencies doesn't seem to work in 3.X (a python binding for the switchvox api).

I'm building a display app that will call any module specified in its config file and display that module's output (a string, or in the future possible a dict) in a tkinter widget.  All my program needs to do is import the 2.7 module and call one function once (every x number of seconds) to receive that string of data.

Comment: If one of the *dependencies* does not run in Python 3, then there is no point in trying to port your module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do you mean the dependencies of the original 3.4 calling program, or the dependencies of the called 2.7 program, or either?

Comment: The 2.7 module is *not a program*. It is Python code only the Python 2.7 interpreter can run. Importing it means it needs to be able to run on Python 3.4 *too*. That's [certainly possible](http://python3porting.com/noconv.html), especially with a [supporting module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six), but if the 2.7 module has dependencies that don't run in 3, then all bets are off.

Comment: Is there any reason why your program has to run on Python 3.4? Why not just run it in 2.7?

Comment: @ColinAtkinson You're right I was weighing that option.  Initially we just thought it would be better to start out in 3.4 because it was newer and might be better supported in the future

Comment: Python 2.7 will be [maintained till 2020](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/), so its not that you should be jumping ship just yet. There are still a large number of libraries not compatible with Python3.

Comment: I do not agree with opinions that you should better give up Python 3. I would suggest the opposite. Follow the first link by Martijn Pieters above. The things like `from __future__ import print_function` can help you. The problem is not that Python 2 is to be supported for a longer time. The problem is that Python 3 is going to be better fast and you will be forced or to rewrite the old code or to be bound to the old code.

Comment: 2to3 might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your python 2.7 code be 3.4 compatible - this way you can import it from 3.4 and use the same classes and functions.

For running you have to run it on different process using python 2.7 - using subprocess.
Assume main27.py has the following line:

```
print 1
```

To run it using subprocess, you do as follow:

```
import subprocess
cmd = [r'c:\python27\python.exe', 'main27.py']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Than in stdout you have the following output:

```
1
```

For more complex data exchange you can use json or pickle using files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Hagai.  Can you explain how one would go about running "a different process" or "subproccess"?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is possible to make your code compatible with both versions. The obvious one and potentially more annoying is the print statement.

Let's say you have the following Python 2.x code:

```
name = "beautiful"
print "Hallo"
print "I mean, hallo ", name
```

The first line works fine in both versions. The second line, can just become:

```
print("Hallo")
```

Which is compatible with both versions too. Note that you can use single or double quotes.

The last line requires a little trick, otherwise, Python 2 will print the brackets as well. In order to make it work the same way in Python 2 as it does in Python 3, you have to import *print_function* from *future*, at the top of your module.

In summary, this is the dual compatible code:

```
#Works in Python 2.x or Python 3.x
from __future__ import print_function

print("Hallo")
print("I mean, hallo ", name)
```

See this [cheat sheet](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html) for more details.